# React css webkit animation is not working after setState

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When I use setState function, it seems that render function works and html changes. However, the css webkit animation does not play again and stops at its final position. Here is my CSS code

```
.enemy{
    width: 80px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-animation:enemy 1s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes enemy{
    100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(1000px);}
}
```

And Here is my JSX code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var GameBoard = createReactClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            gameState: 0,
            heroLoc: 0,
            enemyLoc: 0,
            enemyType : 0,
        }
    },

    gameStart() {
        this.setState({
            gameState: 1
        })
        this.createEnemy();
    },

    changeEnemyType(){
        var type = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
        var loc = Math.round(Math.random());
        this.setState({enemyLoc : loc});
        this.setState({enemyType : type});
    },

    createEnemy(){
        setInterval(this.changeEnemyType, 1000);
    },

    render() {
        var state = this.state
        var enemyCls = state.gameState? ("enemy enemy"+ state.enemyType  + " loc" + state.enemyLoc):"enemy";
        return (
            <div className = "board" >
                <div className="road">
                    <div className={enemyCls} id="enemy"></div>
                </div>
                <span className = { state.gameState? "start hide":"start" } onClick = { this.gameStart }> Start </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

When I click game start bottom, class of enemy changes every second, but css animation does not replay so I can not use EventListener to detect "webkitAnimationEnd".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest it's a problem with your css rather than `React`. What you missed is a value for `animation-iteration-count`.

You can make it works by adding `infinite` to your `-webkit-animation` rule.

`-webkit-animation:enemy 1s linear forwards infinite;`

More information about `animation` can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I was stuck at why the css did not rendered again and play the animation but realized that this style didn't change so it would keep the same even when class in html changed.

Answer (score 1):

it is not a problem of react render method.. Basically the css animation will work continuously only when you add the `infinte` value ... in your case the initial class is "enemy" and after you click on start it will change to something like this--> "`enemy enemy1 loc0`" 
the numbers may change depending on `math.random()`, since your class name is changed it will try to add the properties from the above class `enemy` `enemy1` `loc0` since `enemy1` and `loc0` is not present in your css therefore it will not add anything and coming to your `enemy` class , the properties in that have added already so it will not add again

Answer (score 0):

Change your css class `-webkit-animation:enemy 1s linear forwards;` in `.enemy`

and replace your css with this :

```
.enemy{
    width: 80px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    background: #ccc;     
}
.enemy0{
    -webkit-animation: enemy 1s linear forwards infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes enemy{
    100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(1000px);}
}
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lmvo7v)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion! I found it worked when I add "infinite" after -webkit-animation in .enemy.